# Android: BroadcastReceiver for internet connection

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to get my `BroadcastReceiver` to work but I have the problem when I disconnect the internet connection, I am getting the `Toast` "Please connect the device to the internet.", on the other hand I am getting the same `Toast` "Please connect the device to the internet." When I establish internet connection again. Is something wrong with the class?

```js
package com.bustracker;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ConnectionChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

 @Override
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

  ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
    .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
  NetworkInfo activeNetInfo = connectivityManager
    .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
  boolean isConnected = activeNetInfo != null
    && activeNetInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
  if (isConnected) {
   Toast.makeText(context, "The device is connected to the internet ",
     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   Log.i("NET", "connecte" +isConnected);
  } else {
   Toast.makeText(context, "Please connect the device to the internet.",
     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

 }
}
```

```js
        <receiver android:name=".ConnectionChangeReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: > I am not getting anything when I establish internet connection again - Does that mean you arent getting the toast at all, or the toast still says not connected?

Comment: The Toast still says "Please connect the device to the internet."

Comment: haah you are connecting over wifi or mobile data?

Comment: Now for testing wifi ...but it shall cover both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are getting the mobile data connection not wifi so it still getting you a false even if that the device is connected to get the current `NetworkInfo` regardless

```
NetworkInfo netInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
```